# Are there primes $p=47\cdot 2^n+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples

Are there primes $p=47\cdot 2^n+1$, where $n\in\mathbb Z_+$? Tested for all primes $p<100,000,000$ without equality.

Comment: I have read at least 2 posts on MSE that demonstrated the difficulties of finding primes in form of $a^n+b$ by probabilistic arguments. Your case wouldn’t be much easier.

Comment: Rather than frame your search for primes by bounding $p$, it will be more meaningful to state the limit on $n$ used in the search.

Comment: @hardmath True, but in the experiment I did, I needed fast primes to find numbers like $47$. I should have done separate test runings for $n=1,2,\dots$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. We can start by quick Maple search, yielding for example $n=583$ (`isprime(47*2^583+1)`). Next ones are $n=1483$ and $n=6115$, I haven't found any others yet. We can speed up this search by noting that for certain $n$ it is clear that it cannot be prime. For example if $n$ is even, then we have $47\cdot 2^n+1 \equiv 2\cdot 2^0+1=0 \pmod 3$. Similarly, if $n$ is odd and $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then $47\cdot 2^n+1 \equiv 2\cdot 2^{1}+1=0 \pmod 5$. This reduces search to $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ .

However as pointed out in comments, Maple performs probabilistic primality tests for such large numbers (one strong pseudo-primality test and one Lucas test per documentation https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=isprime), so there is a chance these could be false positives (although no such counter example has been yet found). Anyway further testing with some deterministic approach would be nice, and fortunately there is one very specific to these numbers! (see below)

It turns out these numbers are special case of what is called [Proth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth_number), and you are especially interested in Proth primes. In fact these numbers are popular in large prime search, largest currently known non Mersenne prime (as of 2018) is $10223\cdot 2^{31172165}+1$ (https://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=3). The reason is there is very effective way to check their primality, using something called [Proth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem). Roughly it states:

> If $p=k\cdot 2^n+1$ with $k$ odd and $k<2^n$, and if there exists an integer $a$ for which $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1 \bmod p$, then $p$ is a prime.

So this can be turned into an effective algorithm to verify primality of the cases found above by probabilistic test. And indeed, for $a=3$ and $p=47\cdot 2^{583}+1$ we already have a match, e.g.:

```
a := 3: 
p := 47*2^583+1: 
is((Power(a, (p-1)/2) mod p) = p-1);
```

So putting together, we can run something like (which I am sure could be optimized)

```
m:=1:
do: 
  n := 4*m+3:
  p := 47*2^n+1:
  if isprime(p) then 
    for a from 1 to 10 do 
      if is((Power(a, (p-1)/2) mod p) = p-1) then 
        print('n' = n, 'a' = a): 
      break: 
      end if: 
    end do: 
  end if: 
  m := m+1 
end do:
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether Maple actually does a primality test for numbers that large, or just a "probable" primality test.

Comment: There are guaranteed, practical primality tests for numbers of that size.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Turn's out there is specific test for these using something called Proth's theorem, see an edited answer.

Comment: Interestingly, no primes occur for $6116\le n\le 30000$

Comment: Update: No primes for $6116\le n\le 40000$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch These have been searched to exponent at least 9 million. See for example [Keller: List of primes k*2^n + 1 for k < 300](http://www.prothsearch.com/riesel1.html). See also [this historical PrimeGrid page](https://www.primegrid.com/stats_div_llr.php). The corresponding OEIS entry [Numbers k such that 47*2^k+1 is prime](https://oeis.org/A032373) does not have the newest information about the search limits reached.

Answer (score 8):

Smallest $m\ge0$ such that $2^mn+1$ is prime is [tabulated](https://oeis.org/A040076) at OEIS. The first "interesting" case is the one under discussion here, $n=47$;  it's at most 8 for $n<47$, then $583$ for $n=47$. For $n=383$ it's $6393$, for $n=2897$ it's $9715$, and it's known that for infinitely many $n$ there is no such $m$. See the links at OEIS.